# FIX Can't contact a foreign socket to my own server

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I just made a boost::asio server, it's quite the same as the example from this link.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/chat/chat_server.cpp

I'm on Windows and when I try to connect a local client it's working but all the client that I try to connect from another computer in the same wifi isn't working (I already tried to disable my firewall)

```
void do_accept()
{
    acceptor_.async_accept(socket_,
        [this](boost::system::error_code ec)
    {
        if (!ec)
        {
            std::cout << "Un client est rentre\n";
            std::make_shared<chat_session>(std::move(socket_), room_)->start();
        }

        do_accept();
    });
}

tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
tcp::socket socket_;
chat_room room_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        if (argc < 2)
        {
            std::cerr << "Usage: chat_server <port> [<port> ...]\n";
            return 1;
        }
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        tcp::endpoint endpoint(tcp::v4(), 50000); // Création de la socket du serveur
        chat_server server(io_service, endpoint);

        io_service.run(); // Run des opérations asynchrones
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I found my ip by ipconfig in the cmd and I'm sure to use the good port

Someone know how to solve it ?

Thank's !

Comment: You wifi router may block clients from connecting to each other. In any case, this has nothing to do with C++.

Comment: @Sam: clients on the same network, WiFi or LAN or otherwise, should not be getting blocked by default. Only clients from outside networks should be.  But yes, do check the router settings for possible blockages.

Comment: It is a common feature of WiFi routers to block WiFi clients from direct access to each other.

Comment: My network was set in public and I disabled the private firewall, sorry :( I fixed it